# How to optimize querying for thousands of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, query-optimization, rails-activerecord

Here are three consecutive queries with their Benchmark performance:

```
ids = @Company.projects.submitted.uniq.collect(&:person_id)
  1.370000   0.060000   1.430000 (  3.763946)

@persons = Person.where("id IN (?)", ids)
  0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.332878)

@emails = @persons.collect(&:email).reject(&:blank?)
  16.550000  1.640000  18.190000  (128.002465)
```

`ids` contains almost 10000 ids, and in running the last query I'm seeing:

```
SELECT "persons".* FROM "persons" WHERE (id in (121,142,173,178...14202))
(*1000s ->) User Load (13.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."roleable_type" = 'Person' AND "users"."roleable_id" = 121 LIMIT 1

Indexes on User:
add_index "users", ["roleable_id", "roleable_type"], :name => "index_users_on_roleable_id_and_roleable_type"
add_index "users", ["roleable_type", "roleable_id"], :name => "index_users_on_roleable_type_and_roleable_id"
```

How can I fix what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd query as you have it isn't actually hitting the database.  It's building up an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (a lazy query) that isn't triggered until the 3rd query is called.  You can demonstrate this by adding `.all` to the end of the 2nd query.

To fix the performance issue, you want to get rid of the `IN ()` with a literal list, as this can really hurt database performance for large lists:

```
@persons = Person.joins(:projects).merge(@Company.projects.submitted)
```

You can also do this using a subquery (albeit less efficiently than a JOIN):

```
subquery = @Company.projects.submitted.select("projects.person_id").to_sql
@persons = Person.where("id IN (#{subquery})")
```

If you only want to get the resulting `@emails`, and don't really need the `@persons` collection, you can make this slightly more efficient like so:

```
@email = Person.joins(:projects).merge(@Company.projects.submitted).
                  where("LENGTH(persons.email) > 0").pluck(:email)
```